# CUDA Device Vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I want to send a vector to my kernel. I have vector of floats `h_vec`.

```
thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec = h_vec;
float* pd_vec = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data());
...
kernel<<<grid, block>>>(pd_vec)
```

However in my kernel the vector seems to be filled with zeros and I have no idea why.

```
__global__ void kernel (float* pd_vec)
```

Is it required that I specifically allocate memory for this vector in host with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`?

Comment: In https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html is the same example with the comment: "// Copy host_vector H to device_vector D". Therefor I would assume that this is the correct usage of thrust. Maybe it has to do with the type of `h_vec`? In the example we have a `thrust::host_vector`.

Comment: I thought so maybe but I have `vector<float> h_vec` I did look at the docs before posting

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @molbdnilo Is it not?

Comment: No, this is not a reproducible example. We had to ask for the type of `h_vec` do not know how you filled it, we have to write our own `kernel` before we can run your example, ...

Comment: may you try `thrust::host_vector` or is this just an alias for `std::vector`?

Comment: @jayjey Follow the link and read what it says.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy No it is just a std::vector. Does it need to be a `thrust::host_vector` when copying to `device_vector`?

Comment: @jayjey: No it does not. Please post a complete example, you are wasting everyone's time if you don't (yours included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it required that I specifically allocate memory for this vector in host with cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy?

No. Copy assignment works just fine between thrust containers (host or device) and `std::vector`.

For example:

```
$ module load cuda/10.1

$ cat notreallyno.cu 

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void kernel (float* pd_vec, int n)
{
    if (threadIdx.x < n)
        printf("%d %f \n", threadIdx.x, pd_vec[threadIdx.x]);
}

int main()
{
    {
    std::vector<float> h_vec = { 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f, 6.6f, 7.7f, 8.8f, 9.9f, 10.01f };
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec = h_vec;
    float* pd_vec = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data());

    int n = h_vec.size();
    kernel<<<1, 32>>>(pd_vec, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o notreallyno notreallyno.cu 

$ ./notreallyno 
0 1.100000 
1 2.200000 
2 3.300000 
3 4.400000 
4 5.500000 
5 6.600000 
6 7.700000 
7 8.800000 
8 9.900000 
9 10.010000
```